# KineticJS: Image does not have a Stroke after applying a Filter

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

Using KineticJS 5.1.0

I have a KineticJS image with a stroke. To this image I want to apply a filter. After caching and applying the filter the stroke has gone.

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/confile/qgrjjjq9/) and my demo code:

```
var imageObj = new Image();
      imageObj.onload = function() {
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: 'container',
          width: 600,
          height: 700
        });
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        img = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 250,
          y: 200,
          image: imageObj,
          draggable: true
        });
        var strokeWidthValue = 10;
        img.setOffsetX(img.getWidth() / 2); 
        img.setOffsetY(img.getHeight() / 2); 
        img.stroke("green");  
        img.strokeWidth(strokeWidthValue);
        img.strokeScaleEnabled(false);  
        img.strokeEnabled(true);  

        layer.add(img);
        stage.add(layer);

        img.cache();
        img.filters([Kinetic.Filters.Invert]);
        layer.draw();
      };
       imageObj.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
      imageObj.src =
  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47067729/darth-vader.jpg";
```

Here is the image before I apply the filter:

[image]

And here after I apply the filter:

[image]

**How do I get the stroke back after applying the filter?**

Edit: I also tried to add extra space for the border but the result shows a pink border, where my one should be green. Here is the cache function I tried:

```
    img.cache({
        x: -(img.getWidth() / 2) - strokeWidthValue,
        y: -(img.getHeight() / 2) - strokeWidthValue,
        width: img.getWidth() + (strokeWidthValue * 2),
        height: img.getHeight() + (strokeWidthValue * 2)
    });
```

here is the result:

[image]

The complete example can be found in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/confile/o73ur6pf/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/truefusion/o73ur6pf/8/

When we create a cache and apply a filter to the image, we are able to access the result from `Kinetic.Image._cache.canvas.filter`. We can then convert the result into a data URI by calling `toDataURL()` on the filter canvas. In order to avoid issues when clearing the image cache, we create a new image element and assign it the data URI to its src attribute. Then we set the new image to the Kinetic image object using `img.setImage()`.

```
var image = new Image()
,   data  = img._cache.canvas.filter.toDataURL()
;

image.src = data;
img.setImage(image);
```

You can then safely clear the cache, pass null to unload callback, and have fun!

<s>You have to account for the size of the stroke. In other words, in the img.cache() properties, subtract strokeWidth from X and Y, and add (strokeWidth * 2) to the width and height.</s>

Comment: I did this but as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/confile/o73ur6pf/ The border has a different color and cannot be removed anymore.

Comment: @confile Here's a possible solution http://jsfiddle.net/o73ur6pf/5/ What i did was create a new temp. layer, cloned the image, placed it in the temp layer and converted the image to a data URI, then replaced the image and cleared the cache. (You don't need the timeout as i have it.)

Comment: Isn't that a little bit to much overload to get the image border correctly after applying the filter? There must be a much simpler way.

Comment: @confile http://jsfiddle.net/o73ur6pf/6/ I removed the need to create a temp layer and just used the one from the image cache.

Comment: Would it be faster to use toImage() instead of toDataURL()?

Comment: @confile toImage() uses toDataURL() to convert to an image, so no.

Comment: Is there no other way than using toDataURL() I think this can be quite expensive on mobile devices.

Comment: @confile I would say it would be about as expensive as applying an invert filter to the original image.

Comment: Ok this means that I need the doubled time to apply a filter. I like your solution but isn't there a faster way to apply a filter?

Comment: There is something wrong with your solution. If you set imageObj.onload = null; at the end of the onload function it does not work anymore. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/confile/cc39t91k/

Comment: @confile It turns out I was pulling from the wrong canvas, and that `clearCache()` was clearing more than I thought. Fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/truefusion/o73ur6pf/8/